# Connect to a webservice through a docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

There is a docker network: `docker network create nginx-proxy`

Then two web servers are running inside Docker containers.

- first container, contains an webserver that exposes an API (only to be used by the other app on the same docker network). The `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-api:
    image: node:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./:/api
    working_dir: /api
    command: npm run start

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

- second container contains an app that consume the API. The `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    image: node:alpine
    environment:
      API_URL: ???
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm run start

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Somewhere in the code of this nodejs app, it tries to connect to the API with a code like this:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL

const getSomethingFromApi = jsonArgs =>
  fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonArgs)
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
```

**How can I configure the docker files for the app in the second container to consume the API from the first container?**

Comment: Generally container name should be used as a host name, try putting `http://my-api` into `API_URL`. You can also exec into a container (`docker exec -it <container name> ash`) and try to ping API from your app container.

Comment: If your container is alpine-based, you might probably cannot ping grom there, since ping won't be installed. But I agree with Igor : http://my-api should do, and maybe http://my-api:<exposed port> provided it's not 80.
And to ensure your api is started, you can use the "depends_on" clause within your consumer's compose and about the provider.

Comment: `my-api:<exposed>` works! Thank you. I wonder where I should have read that in the docs… Anyways, please answer the the question so I can accept.